# How optimize below code to determine the total number of prime numbers below 1,000,000,000 have the sum of their digits equal to 14 in C?

Tags: c

/*Write a program to determine the total number of prime numbers below 1000,000,000 have the sum of their digits equal to 14? Make sure the execution time is few seconds.*/

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main() {
  int i, j, count = 0, temp = 0, n, ans = 0, tot = 0;
  for (i = 1; i <= 1000000000; i++) {
    for (j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++) {
      if (i % j == 0) {
        count++;
      }
    }

    if (count == 0) {
      n = i;
      while (n != 0) {
        temp = n % 10;
        n = n / 10;
        ans = ans + temp;
      }
      if (ans == 14) {
        tot++;
        printf("%d,", i);
      }
      ans = 0;
      temp = 0;
    }
    count = 0;
  }
  // printf("%d:\n",tot);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put the most complex (the most iterations) `for` loops in the interior if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Two simply improvements (amongst other):

1: Rather than iterate to `i/2`, iterate to the square root of `i` - that is `j*j <= i`.<sup>**</sup>  This is a huge speed-up.

2: Quit loop once a factor found.

```
// for(j=2;j<=i/2;j++) {
//  if(i%j==0) {
//    count++;
//  }
//}
for(j=2;j<=i/j;j++) { // _much_ lower limit
  if(i%j==0) {
    count++;
    break; // No need to find more factors: `i` is not a prime.
  }
}
```

---

Functionality: Inside `if(count==0)`, I'd expect `ans == 0` before `while(n!=0)`.

---

<sup>**</sup> Use `j<=i/j` to prevent overflow.  A good compiler will see a nearby `i%j` and often perform both `i/j, i%j` for the time cost of one.

Answer (score 1):

The digit-sum function could also use a early return like:

```
   int dsum14(int n) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (; n; n /= 10)
            if ((sum += n % 10) > 14)
                return 0;
        return sum == 14 ? 1 : 0;
    }
```

But how to combine the (efficient) prime search and this sum condition?

```
int n, cnt = 0;
for (n = 3; n < 1000*1000*1000; n += 2)
    if (n%3 && n%5 && dsum14(n) && n%7 && n%11 && n%13)
        cnt++;
```

This gives `77469` in 1.5 seconds. With `dsum()` at either end of the logical chain it is almost double.

The `&& n%7 && n%11 && n%13` part would be replaced by a function using a list of primes up to about 32000 (square root of max).

---

...or you can optimize it to **0.1 seconds**, by tweaking the digsum function.

There are "only" 575 three-digit numbers 000-999 with sum 14 or less. So I prepare them and combine three of them to get a 9-digit number. Generating them instead of filtering them.

The tail looks like:

```
920000021
920000201
920001011
920010011
920100011
920100101
920101001
921001001
931000001
total count: 22588

real    0m0.098s
user    0m0.100s
sys     0m0.002s
```

And the start:

```
59
149
167
239
257
293
347
383
419
```

Not 100% sure if it's correct, but the total count also seems reasonable.

It all relies on the given max of 1000 Mio. `digsum_prime()` uses it to build the candidate number from three (almost) equal parts.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int parr[5000] = {3};

struct {
    int tri, sum;
} ts[999]; 

void primarr(void) {
    int maxn = 32000;
    int i = 1;
    for (int n = 5; n < maxn; n += 2)
        for (int div = 3;; div += 2) {
            if (!(n % div))
                break;
            if (div*div > n) {
                parr[i++] = n;
                break;
            }
        }    
}

int isprime(int n) {
    for(int i = 0;; i++) {
        if (!(n % parr[i]))
            return 0;
        if (parr[i]*parr[i] > n)
            return 1;
    }
}

int dsum(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (; n; n /= 10) 
        sum += n % 10;
    return sum;
}
int tsarr(void) {
    int i = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n < 1000; n++) {
        int digsum = dsum(n);
        if (digsum <= 14) {
            ts[i].tri = n;
            ts[i].sum = digsum;
            i++;
        }
    }    
    return i;
}

int digsum_prime() {

    int cnt = 0;
    int tslen = tsarr();
    printf("tslen: %d\n", tslen);

    int high, mid, low;
    int sum, num;

    for (high = 0; high < tslen; high++) { 

        if(ts[high].sum > 13)
            continue;
        for (mid = 0; mid < tslen; mid++) { 

            if(ts[mid].sum + ts[high].sum > 13)
                continue;
            sum = ts[mid].sum + ts[high].sum;

            for (low = 0; low < tslen; low++)   
                if (ts[low].tri % 2) 
                    if(ts[low].sum + sum == 14) {

                        num = ts[high].tri * 1000*1000 
                            + ts[mid] .tri * 1000 
                            + ts[low] .tri;

                        if (isprime(num)) {
                            cnt++;        
                            printf("%d\n", num);
                        }
                    }
        }
    }
    
    return cnt; 
}

int main(void) {
    primarr();
    printf("total count: %d\n", digsum_prime());

}
```

---

Changing 13-13-14 to 3-3-4 (but same preparation part) gives an overview - in **0.005** s!

```
tslen: 575
13
31
103
211
1021
1201
2011
3001
10111
20011
20101
21001
100003
102001
1000003
1011001
1020001
1100101
2100001
10010101
10100011
20001001
30000001
101001001
200001001
total count: 25

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m0.000s
```

> Make sure the execution time is **few seconds**.

oops

But the limits of OP are well chosen: a naive approach takes *several* seconds.